# How to get return from request function in node.js

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio, scraper

So I made site scraper and I want to use string in other function from this request function but i just cant return it for example. And im not sure how pipe works.

```
request(realAnswer, function (error, response, html) {

  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var tree = $('.qa-answer-field');
    var final = tree.children().eq(1).text();//i want to use this final as a sting in other fucntion

  }

}).pipe(final);
```

this solution works fine but i can only write my result in console...

```
  request(realAnswer, function (error, response, html) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var tree = $('.qa-answer-field');
        var final = tree.children().eq(1).text();
          if(final) 
            console.log("Response:  \n"+final);
          else
            console.error("Response doesnt exist!");
      }

    });
```

So does anyone can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var usemepls = 'fake'
  request(realAnswer, function (error, response, html) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var tree = $('.qa-answer-field');
        var final = tree.children().eq(1).text();
          if(final) 
            console.log("Response:  \n"+final);
            usemepls = final.toString() // <-- if you dont want a string just replace the .toString()
          else
            console.error("Response doesnt exist!");
      }

    })

    console.log('usemepls: ' + usemepls)
```

Or you can use object strings like

```
  var usemepls = {}
  request(realAnswer, function (error, response, html) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var tree = $('.qa-answer-field');
        var final = tree.children().eq(1).text();
          if(final) 
            console.log("Response:  \n"+final);
            usemepls.test1 = final.toString() // <-- if you dont want a string just replace the .toString()
          else
            console.error("Response doesnt exist!");
      }

    })

    console.log('usemepls.test1: ' + usemepls.test1)
```

Or you can use a function

```
function function1() {
  request(realAnswer, function (error, response, html) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var tree = $('.qa-answer-field');
        var final = tree.children().eq(1).text();
          if(final) 
            console.log("Response:  \n"+final);
            return final
          else
            console.error("Response doesnt exist!");
      }

    })
} // function function1() {

    console.log( 'final: ' + function1() )
```

You should look more behind the javascript/node.js basics. It will make everything easier for you.